# Array of string in OPL

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, modeling, cplex, opl

how to make 2d array of strings in Cplex

//indics

{string} cluster=...;

setof(string) darkstore =...;

setof(string)demandpoint =...;

//data

cluster={chav,sree};

demandpoint=[{tsnami,adholokam,neelambari,ashrayam},{tg,pd,cp,dt}];

darkstore=[{dilucia,quickstart,babystores,yonnesbakery},{a,b,c,d}];

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

.mod

```
{string} cluster=...;

string darkstore [cluster][1..4]=...;

string demandpoint  [cluster][1..4]=...;
```

.dat

```
cluster={chav,sree};

demandpoint=[[tsnami,adholokam,neelambari,ashrayam],[tg,pd,cp,dt]];

darkstore=[[dilucia,quickstart,babystores,yonnesbakery],[a,b,c,d]];
```

work fine